# Hiding the navbar toggle button for large and medium scale device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to develop a responsive website using bootstrap, in which I am designing a navbar which contains a toggle button that should only show up when the browser is squeezed to -sm scale device.

I tried to hide it by giving my button a class as visible-sm, it didn't work.
The toggle button is always visible no matter whatever be the screen size, I want this button only to be visible in small screen size.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler visible-sm" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

my jfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/t1yodsxf/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show the button only on `sm` screen size you can use the classes [`d-none d-sm-block d-md-none`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements). The button is now **only** visible on `sm` screen size, not on smaller (`xs`) or larger (>= `md`) screen sizes:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler d-none d-sm-block d-md-none" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

To show the button only on the `xs` screen size you can use the classes `d-block d-sm-none`:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler d-block d-sm-none" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

The `visible-sm` class is not available on Bootstrap. There is only a [`visible` and `invisible`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/visibility/) class to set the visibility of an element.

Comment: what if i want this button,only to be visible on xs, i used .d-block .d-sm-none, but by doing so, button is also visible on -lg.

Comment: Only `xs` the classes `d-block d-sm-none` have to work: https://jsfiddle.net/pxd237yL/